# JavaScript getting certain information from within a collection

Tags: javascript

I am confused on how I should go about getting information which seems to be in a collection, from the data in the link, (which may be added to/removed from). I am trying to get the size of 'members', and if the size is zero, execute some code.
https://pastebin.com/4dN513UQ
Here's an example of the data -

```
'423109097190064130' => VoiceChannel {
  type: 'voice',
  id: '423109097190064130',
  name: 'testChannel',
  position: 8,
  parentID: '422574541387333633',
  permissionOverwrites: Collection { '376517191077593089' => [Object] },
  bitrate: 64,
  userLimit: 0,
  guild:
   Guild {
     members: [Object],
     channels: [Object],
     roles: [Object],
     presences: [Object],
     available: true,
     id: '376517191077593089',
     name: 'The Organization',
     icon: 'a9ade7c63cc89c559f8e1fa6f6b7b145',
     splash: null,
     region: 'us-central',
     memberCount: 57,
     large: false,
     features: [],
     applicationID: null,
     afkTimeout: 3600,
     afkChannelID: '376889682736447518',
     systemChannelID: null,
     embedEnabled: undefined,
     verificationLevel: 3,
     explicitContentFilter: 2,
     joinedTimestamp: 1520955532833,
     ownerID: '197484892093677568',
     _rawVoiceStates: Collection {},
     emojis: [Object] },
  members: Collection {} },
```

Comment: Object.keys() ?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help you because you've only shown us the object structure of a Voice Channel, but we don't know what `members` looks like or what you want to do with them.

This looks like the Discord API, so it would be useful to see your actual code that retrieves this data. Presumably you are using some kind of client library (in NodeJS or PHP for example) to make the API request.